# QListView show text when list is empty

Tags: qt, qlistview

I want to show some text (like "No items") when there are no items in QListView.
I tried to override paintEvent method of QListView, but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: For the future: you need to show your code. It doesn't matter that you've tried - we need to see your code to help you out, otherwise we have to write it from scratch and your tries are useless for us to help you. For every question like yours, one could answer a whole bunch of well-posed questions where a quick look at the code reveals what's wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code below shows a simple way of doing it by overloading the `paintEvent` method of the view. Painting of the text should probably use the style mechanism to obtain the font and pen/brush, but I'll leave that up for grabs by a keen editor.

It uses Qt 5 and its C++11 features, doing it the Qt 4 or pre-C++11 way would require a QObject-deriving class with a slot to connect to the spin box's `valueChanged` signal. The implementation of `ListView` doesn't need to change between Qt 4 and Qt 5.

[image: screenshot]

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class ListView : public QListView {
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
      QListView::paintEvent(e);
      if (model() && model()->rowCount(rootIndex()) > 0) return;
      // The view is empty.
      QPainter p(this->viewport());
      p.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "No Items");
   }
public:
   ListView(QWidget* parent = 0) : QListView(parent) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QWidget window;
   QFormLayout layout(&window);
   ListView view;
   QSpinBox spin;
   QStringListModel model;
   layout.addRow(&view);
   layout.addRow("Item Count", &spin);
   QObject::connect(&spin, (void (QSpinBox::*)(int))&QSpinBox::valueChanged,
                    [&](int value){
      QStringList list;
      for (int i = 0; i < value; ++i) list << QString("Item %1").arg(i);
      model.setStringList(list);
   });
   view.setModel(&model);
   window.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a QListView, you probably have a custom model containing data you want to display. This is maybe the best place to returns "No items" when your model is empty.

Comment: That mixes up presentation and the business side of things. Such a model would need to be the veritable view model, acting as a proxy model.